# I wanna check before insert or update mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

check before insert or update mysql 
my code doesn't work I have no idea why

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM downloads WHERE name = '" . $details['name']."' " ;
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

if( mysql_num_rows($result) === 0) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO downloads (name, idu) VALUES ('".$details['name']."', '".$details['idu']."')";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
   }
else{

    $sql2 = "UPDATE downloads SET idu='".$details['idu']."' WHERE name='". $details['name'] ."'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql2);

    }
```

Comment: "mysql_" ??? That has been obsolete for *years*.

Comment: **Stop** using deprecated/removed `mysql_*`API. Use `mysqli_*`or `PDO`. Also learn about prepared Statements to prevent SQL injection

Comment: You're using outdated functions and your queries are open for injection attacks! http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: As @GordonLinoff already mentioned you should at least upgrade to http://php.net/mysqli or even better use http://php.net/PDO.
In addition, if you only want to check if there is a record so you can do update instead of insert you should have a look at this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: Aside from all that, what is your actual question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is generally handled using `on duplicate key update`:

```
INSERT INTO downloads (name, idu)
    VALUES (?, ?)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE idu = VALUES(idu);
```

For this to work, you need for `name` to be declared `unique` or have a `unique` index:

```
ALTER TABLE downloads ADD CONSTRAINT unq_downloads_name UNIQUE (name);
```

The `?` are placeholders for *parameters*.  Don't munge query strings with parameter values!  Doing so makes the query harder to optimize, to debug, and opens it to SQL injection attacks.  For better or worse, the no-longer supported "mysql_" functions don't support parameters, so that is another reason to update your code (and your skills!) to "mysqli_".

Answer (score 0):

```
`INSERT INTO xxxxxxx
(dd1, dd2, dd3, dd4, dd5, dd6, dd7, dd8, dd9, dd0)
select 'config', '9', NULL, 'appname', '2016-10-20 11:55:01', NULL, 'xxx', '2007-09-18 16:31:03', NULL, NULL
FROM dual 
Where not exists (select * from xxx where dd2 = '9' and dd4 = 'appname' and
dd6 is NULL and  dd0 is NULL) ;`
```

```
`UPDATE xxx
SET 
dd1 = 'config', dd2 = '9', dd3 = NULL, dd4 = 'appname', dd5 = '2016-10-20 11:55:01',
dd6 = NULL, dd7 = 'xxx', dd8 = '2007-09-18 16:31:03', dd9 = NULL, dd0 = NULL
Where 
dd2 = '9' and dd4 = 'appname' and
dd6 is NULL and  dd0 is NULL;`
```

In this way you can deal with the unique key has NULL value

Comment: It would be helpful to format your code for display.
Here is how to do that:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

You should also add general formatting to your SQL with all caps keywords and newlines between clauses to make it more readable.